# How to check the version of wcf ria services installed on a computer?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Wcf ria services installed by Silverlight x Tools for visual studio 201x SPx,  but how to check what the version of wcf ria service installed on a computer?

Answer (score 0):

I did this: go to add/remove programs and look for 'ria'